# What is the most efficient way in Selenium to open and process links within a loop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

With Selenium and BeautifulSoap i am trying to scrape a WebPage. In general this works fine. Please find the code below.

On this page there are listed some *Categories*. The depth is 4 levels. On each level i have 20 items/links.

My question is: what is the most efficient way to open and process these links within an loop?

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

wd.get("url")

source = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
items = soup.select('ul[data-card-id="tree-list0972"]')
for item in items:
  ul = item.find('ul')
  for li in ul:
    print(li.a.get('href') + ',' + li.a.text)
    cats = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    # Here i do need to open the link from the url list (3 levels deep)
    cats.get(h + domain + li.a.get('href'))

    WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeout=3)
    cats.close 
wd.close
```

Comment: Why do you need to open the separate browser instances in the first place? (besides other problems in the code)

Comment: Hm, to open the urls? I think you want to say that the page source is stored in variables and by looping through the variables items i dont need to open a new instance of the browser, right?

Comment: I'm saying that just use the same browser instance to open the URL.

Comment: How do you want to do this? for each link do you want to open in a same browser tab or do you wish to open in new tab/browser instance  ? Also, how may links do you have in total ? one the link has been loaded, do you want to retrieve anything ?

Comment: But just by using the same instance in the loop i would loose the html source of the higher levels. And what are the 'other problems in the code'?

Comment: @cruisepandey: I have a root page. I extract from this page a category list with URLs. Each Category has Childcategories and each Childcategory again Childcategories and so on ... On each page i need to extract some kind of information from severals divs for each category. Then step again in the loop higher, next category, drill down, collect information and go back ...

Comment: In many cases it is possible to retrieve data without selenium at all (requests, beautifulsoup approach) that would be far more efficient (fast) if possible but depends on the url and required data

Comment: It looks as if you parse the source of an initial page to identify the other pages to open. My first question would therefore be, why you need to parse the source code and cannot just retrieve the links using selenium? Then I do not understand, why you must create a new browser instance for each other page? It seems you already have a the url's in memory so you could just load each individual url within the first instance.

Comment: what's the url? Quite possible the data is available through API?

Comment: @doberkofler: Understood. I have the code mostly and now i work just with one single instance and store the retrieved urls in memory. To be honest, i haven't ever worked with Selenium before, so that Selenium is just another scraping tool for me. If you say 'why not use selenium for retrieving the links', what do you mean with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try implement your use case without BeautifulSoap in a structure like this:

**1. create web driver**

```py
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
```

**2. open the "main" web page**

```py
wd.get("url")
```

**3. get all elements**

```py
elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul[data-card-id="..."])
```

**4. get the url of each element**

```py
pages = []
for element in elements:
   pages.append(element.get_attribute('href')
```

**5. process each page**

```py
for page in pages:
   wd.get(page)
   # ...
```